# Hamburger icon not clickable above relative positioned elements

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, sticky, hamburger-menu

I am working on a website and ran into a little problem. Everything works nice but the hamburger icon stops to work or is not clickable when the sticky navbar is above a relative positioned element like a div-block. I am using Tailwindcss and a very simple js script. I hope somebody can help me with that.

Here the navbar code:

```
<!-- Hambuger Icon Manu Balken-->
    <div class="sticky top-0 lg:hidden px-4 py-4 flex justify-between items-center bg-white opacity-95 drop-shadow">
        <button class="block navbar-burger flex items-center text-blue-600 pt-5 pl-2 pb-2">
            <span>
                <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 mb-1 "></span>
                <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 my-1"></span>
                <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 mt-1"></span>
            </span>
        </button>
        <a class="block px-4 py-4 leading-loose text-xs text-center leading-none hover:border border hover:border-black hover:bg-white hover:text-black bg-black text-white rounded-md font-serif"
            href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar-menu relative z-50 hidden">
        <div class="navbar-backdrop fixed inset-0 bg-gray-800 opacity-25"></div>
        <!--mobile side menu-->
        <nav
            class="fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 flex flex-col w-screen md:w-5/6 md:w-4/6 py-6 px-6 bg-white border-r font-serif overflow-y-auto">
            <div class="flex items-center mb-8">
                <button class="navbar-close h-8">
                    <span class="block">
                        <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 rotate-45 translate-y-1"></span>
                        <span class="block opacity-0 bg-black w-8 h-0.5"></span>
                        <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 -rotate-45 "></span>

                    </span>
                </button>


            </div>
            <div>

                <ul class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded"
                            href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded"
                            href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded"
                            href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded"
                            href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded"
                            href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-20">
                <p class="my-4 text-xs text-center text-gray-800">
                    <span class="block my-3"><a href="tel:+12344567">Tel.: +12345678</a></span>
                    <span class="block my-3"><a
                            href="mailto:info@xyz.de?subject=Hochzeitsplanner gesucht">Email:
                            info@xyz.de</a></span>
                </p>
                <div class="pt-6 ">
                    <a class="block px-4 py-3 mb-3 leading-loose text-xs text-center font-semibold leading-none hover:border border hover:border-black hover:bg-white hover:text-black bg-black text-white rounded-md"
                        href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <!---- HEADER-->
    <header class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white">
        <div class="">
            <img class=" w-52 h-52 lg:w-80 lg:h-80" src="./assets/img/xyz.png"
                alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="flex justify-center gap-8 pt-4 pb-8">
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/img/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
        </div>
    </header>

<!---Desktop Menu-->
    <nav class="hidden sticky top-0 px-4 pt-4 pb-5 lg:flex justify-between items-center bg-white drop-shadow">


        <ul
            class=" absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 lg:flex lg:mx-auto lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto lg:space-x-6">
            <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="text-gray-300">

            </li>
            <li><a class="text-sm text-blue-600 font-bold" href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="text-gray-300">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                        d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="text-gray-300">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                        d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="text-gray-300">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                        d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="hidden lg:inline-block lg:ml-auto lg:mr-3 py-2 px-6 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 text-sm text-gray-900 font-bold  rounded-sm transition duration-200"
            href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
        <a class="hidden lg:inline-block py-2 px-6 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-sm text-white font-bold rounded-xl transition duration-200"
            href="#">Sign up</a>
    </nav>
```

And here's the js script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // open
            const burger = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger');
            const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-menu');

            if (burger.length && menu.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < burger.length; i++) {
                    burger[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                            menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            // close
            const close = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-close');
            const backdrop = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-backdrop');

            if (close.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
                    close[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                            menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            if (backdrop.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < backdrop.length; i++) {
                    backdrop[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
                            menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

I tried different z-values but without any effect. It works once I remove the relative class from one of the div blocks, but I definitely need that to position some elements. Something about the overlapping creates problems.

Comment: Not really sure, but you might need to prevent the event from bubbling up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/932282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying a positive `z-index` to the elements that have `position: sticky` so that they appear higher in the stacking order than any `position: relative` elements that appear afterwards in the source order. For example, I have added `z-50` to the two elements that have `sticky`, alongside a translucent `relative`-positioned `<div>` as per your description to demonstrate that this fixes the issue.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // open
  const burger = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger');
  const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-menu');

  if (burger.length && menu.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < burger.length; i++) {
      burger[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
          menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // close
  const close = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-close');
  const backdrop = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-backdrop');

  if (close.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
          menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  if (backdrop.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < backdrop.length; i++) {
      backdrop[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < menu.length; j++) {
          menu[j].classList.toggle('hidden');
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="sticky top-0 lg:hidden px-4 py-4 flex justify-between items-center bg-white opacity-95 drop-shadow z-50">
  <button class="block navbar-burger flex items-center text-blue-600 pt-5 pl-2 pb-2">
    <span>
      <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 mb-1"></span>
      <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 my-1"></span>
      <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 mt-1"></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <a class="block px-4 py-4 leading-loose text-xs text-center leading-none hover:border border hover:border-black hover:bg-white hover:text-black bg-black text-white rounded-md font-serif" href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar-menu relative z-50 hidden">
  <div class="navbar-backdrop fixed inset-0 bg-gray-800 opacity-25"></div>
  <!--mobile side menu-->
  <nav class="fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 flex flex-col w-screen md:w-5/6 md:w-4/6 py-6 px-6 bg-white border-r font-serif overflow-y-auto">
    <div class="flex items-center mb-8">
      <button class="navbar-close h-8">
        <span class="block">
          <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 rotate-45 translate-y-1"></span>
          <span class="block opacity-0 bg-black w-8 h-0.5"></span>
          <span class="block bg-black w-8 h-0.5 -rotate-45"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <li class="mb-1">
          <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
          <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded" href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
          <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
          <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-1">
          <a class="block p-4 text-sm font-serif text-black hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-600 rounded" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-20">
      <p class="my-4 text-xs text-center text-gray-800">
        <span class="block my-3"><a href="tel:+12344567">Tel.: +12345678</a></span>
        <span class="block my-3"><a href="mailto:info@xyz.de?subject=Hochzeitsplanner gesucht">Email: info@xyz.de</a></span>
      </p>
      <div class="pt-6">
        <a class="block px-4 py-3 mb-3 leading-loose text-xs text-center font-semibold leading-none hover:border border hover:border-black hover:bg-white hover:text-black bg-black text-white rounded-md" href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!---- HEADER-->
<header class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white">
  <div class="">
    <img class="w-52 h-52 lg:w-80 lg:h-80" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex justify-center gap-8 pt-4 pb-8">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20" alt="Facebook" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20?" alt="Twitter" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20?0" alt="Instagram" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20?1" alt="Pinterest" height="20px" width="20px" /></a>
  </div>
</header>

<!---Desktop Menu-->
<nav class="hidden sticky top-0 px-4 pt-4 pb-5 lg:flex justify-between items-center bg-white drop-shadow z-50">
  <ul class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 lg:flex lg:mx-auto lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto lg:space-x-6">
    <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="text-gray-300"></li>
    <li><a class="text-sm text-blue-600 font-bold" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="text-gray-300">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
      </svg>
    </li>
    <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="text-gray-300">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
      </svg>
    </li>
    <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li class="text-gray-300">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 current-fill" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 5v0m0 7v0m0 7v0m0-13a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
      </svg>
    </li>
    <li><a class="text-sm text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="hidden lg:inline-block lg:ml-auto lg:mr-3 py-2 px-6 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 text-sm text-gray-900 font-bold rounded-sm transition duration-200" href="#">Jetzt anfragen!</a>
  <a class="hidden lg:inline-block py-2 px-6 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-sm text-white font-bold rounded-xl transition duration-200" href="#">Sign up</a>
</nav>

<div class="h-[200vh] relative bg-red-500/50">
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Could you explain what was the issue? Like how does the sticky attribute interact with the relative attribute in staked elements? Or do have a source I might read about it?

Comment: [Read about stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context)